# From Perl, spawn a shell, configure it, and fork the STDOUT

Tags: perl, shell, fork, pipe, stdout

I use a Perl script to configure and spawn a compiled program, that needs a subshell configured a certain way, so I use `$returncode = system("ulimit -s unlimited; sg ourgroup 'MyExecutable.exe'");`

I want to capture and parse the STDOUT from that, but I need it forked, so that the output can be checked while the job is still running. This question comes close:
[How can I send Perl output to a both STDOUT and a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634508/how-can-i-send-perl-output-to-a-both-stdout-and-a-variable) The highest-rated answer describes a function called `backtick()` that creates a child process, captures `STDOUT`, and runs a command in it with `exec()`.

But the calls I have require multiple lines to configure the shell. One solution would be to create a disposable shell script:

```
#disposable.sh
    #!/bin/sh
    ulimit -s unlimited
    sg ourgroup 'MyExecutable.exe'
```

I could then get what I need either with `backtick(disposable.sh)` or `open(PROCESS,'disposable.sh|')`.

But I'd really rather not make a scratch file for this. `system()` happily accepts multi-line command strings. How can I get `exec()` or `open()` to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use shell's power (that includes loops, variables, but also multiple command execution), you have to invoke the shell (`open(..., 'xxx|')` doesn't do that).

You can pass your shell script to the shell with the `-c` option of the shell (another possibility would be to pipe the commands to the shell, but that's more difficult IMHO).
That means calling the `backtick` function from the other answer like this:

```
backtick("sh", "-c", "ulimit -s unlimited; sg ourgroup 'MyExecutable.exe'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Expect should be used as you are **interacting** with your program:  http://metacpan.org/pod/Expect
Assuming /bin/bash on your *nix matches something like ***bash-3.2$*** the below program can   be used to launch number of commands using $exp->send on bash console and output from each command can then be parsed for further actions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Expect;
my $command="/bin/bash";
my @parameters;
my $exp= new Expect;
$exp->raw_pty(1);
$exp->spawn($command);
$exp->expect(5, '-re', 'bash.*$');
$exp->send("who \n");
$exp->expect(10, '-re', 'bash.*$');
my @output = $exp->before(); 
print "Output of who command is @output \n";
$exp->send("ls -lt \n");
$exp->expect(10, '-re', 'bash.*$');
my @output = $exp->before(); 
print "Output of ls command is @output \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The system `tee` with backticks will do this, no?

```
my $output = `(ulimit -s unlimited; sg ourgroup 'MyExecutable.exe') | tee /dev/tty`;
```

or modify Alnitak's `backticks` (so it does use a subshell)?

```
my $cmd = "ulimit -s unlimiited ; sg ourgroup 'MyExecutable.exe'";
my $pid = open(CMD, "($cmd) |");
my $output;
while (<CMD>) {
   print STDOUT $_;
   $output .= $_;
}
close CMD;
```