# How can I redefine 'open' properly in Perl?

Tags: perl, built-in, redefine

Some time ago, I ask a question: [How do I redefine built in Perl functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651124/how-do-i-redefine-built-in-perl-functions)

And the answers have served me well. I have a package that overrides Perl's 'open' function enabling me to log file access.

Now I've come to a case that breaks the functionality of the original code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub myopen (*;@) {
  my $p;
  my $retval = CORE::open($p, $_[1]);
  {
    no strict;
    *{"main::$_[0]"} = $p;
  }
  return $retval;
}

BEGIN {
  *CORE::GLOBAL::open = *myopen;
};

my @a = (1, 2, 3);

open(CHECK, ">dump") or print "UNABLE TO OPEN DUMPER FILE: $!\n";
print CHECK "test\n";
print CHECK Data::Dumper->Dump(\@a);
close CHECK
```

Now I get this message:

```
Can't locate object method "CHECK" via package "Data::Dumper"
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: If that's the complete error, it's using indiirect object syntax on the wrong object. Try CHECK->print( ... ) and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 8):

**Try using a name other than "CHECK"**.

"CHECK" is a special function which is called during compile time, and you really shouldn't use it.

```
$ open CHECK , '<', 'foo.txt'; 
Took 0.00224494934082031 seconds.

Runtime error: Undefined subroutine &Devel::REPL::Plugin::Packages::DefaultScratchpad::CHECK called at (eval 329) line 5.

$ open CHECKS , '<', 'foo.txt'; 
Took 0.00155806541442871 seconds.

$
```

- [More on 'CHECK'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END)

**Why that specific error?**

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 'print CHECK Data::Dumper 1';
print 'Data::Dumper'->CHECK(1);
```

Also, you're using **global file handles**, which are problematic.

use this notation:

```
open my $fh, '<' , $foo ; 
print <$fh>;
close $fh;
```

These are extra beneficial is they self-close when they go out of scope.

Comment: +1, nice analysis of the problem and you proposed the right solution (open()'s saner 3-arg syntax, with the filehandle in a lexical variable). And, I HATE PERL FOR THINGS LIKE THIS.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Using PerlCritic will bring some Perl love back ;-)

Comment: @draegtun: Perl::Critic looks interesting (though I fear what it will say about my large codebase of old, old code... :) )

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

```
> perl -MData::Dumper -e'local*_=*STDOUT;print _ Data::Dumper->Dump([2]);'
Can't locate object method "_" via package "Data::Dumper" at -e line 1.
```

to

```
> perl -MData::Dumper -e'local*_=*STDOUT;print _ ( Data::Dumper->Dump([2]) );'
$VAR1 = 2;
```

I used a different name from "STDOUT" because it seems to only gets the indirect object wrong when it's not a built-in handle.

Answer (score 1):

This will work and without producing the error...

```
 print {*CHECK} Data::Dumper->Dump(\@a);
```

This stops it being confused has an ["Indirect Object Syntax"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax)

However I do recommend steering clear of using CHECK and other [special named code blocks in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) and using lexical variables for filehandles is the preferred method. [PBP](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?perl_best_practices)