# redefining or overloading backticks

Tags: perl

I have a lot of legacy code which shells out a lot, what i want to do is add a `require` or minimal code changes to make the backticks do something different, for instance print instead of running code

i tried using `use subs` but i couldn't get it to take over backticks or qx (i did redefine system which is one less thing to worry about)

i also tried to make a package:

```
package thingmbob;
use Data::Dumper;
use overload    '``'    => sub { CORE::print "things!:\t", Dumper \@_};
#this works for some reason
$thingmbob::{'(``'}('ls');
#this does the standard backtick operation
`ls`
```

unfourtunatly, I have no experience in OOP perl and my google-fu skills are failing me, could some one point me in the right direction?

caveat:
I'm in a closed system with a few cpan modules preinstalled, odds are that i don't have any fancy modules preinstalled and i absolutely cannot get new ones

I'm on perl5.14

edit:

for the sake of completeness i want to add my (mostly) final product

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe = sub {
        print Dumper(\@_);
        @internal = readpipe(@_);
        if(wantarray){
            return @internal;
        }else{
            return join('',@internal);
        }
    };
}
```

I want it to print what its about to run and then run it. the `wantarray` is important because without it scalar context does not work

Comment: `overload` won't help you. That's for when the current object that has the overload is used in a certain context, like `DateTime->now + 5` would magically work.

Comment: It seems that `qx` cannot be overridden.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/651990/4653379).  (I am _not_ saying that you cannot accomplish what you want, in some way :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [perlmonks article](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=907345) explains how to do it. You can overwrite the [`readpipe`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readpipe.html) built-in.

> EXPR is executed as a system command. The collected standard output of the command is returned. In scalar context, it comes back as a single (potentially multi-line) string. In list context, returns a list of lines (however you've defined lines with `$/` (or `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` in `English`)). This is the internal function implementing the `qx/EXPR/` operator, but you can use it directly. The `qx/EXPR/` operator is discussed in more detail in I/O Operators in perlop. If EXPR is omitted, uses `$_` .

You need to put this into a `BEGIN` block, so it would make sense to not `require`, but `use` it instead to make it available as early as possible.

Built-ins are overridden using the [`CORE::GLOBAL::` namespace](http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html).

```
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::readpipe = sub {
        print "@_";
    }
}

print qx/ls/;
print `ls`;
```

This outputs:

```
ls1ls1
```

Where the `ls` is the `@_` and the `1` is the return value of `print` inside the overridden sub.

Alternatively, there is [ex::override](https://metacpan.org/pod/ex::override), which does the same under the hood, but with less weird internals.