# How can I modify the output of the PRINT function using Tie with a Moose implementation?

Tags: perl, printing, stdout, moose, tie

I can't exactly wrap my head around TIE just yet but the examples ( [example-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387702/how-can-i-hook-into-perls-print) [example-2](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/pod/perltie.pod) [example-3](http://www.yaldex.com/perl-tutorial-3/0596002270_pmodperl-chp-6-sect-4.html) ) I've seen so far use a non-Moosy implementation, is there anyway to do this:

```
package MY_STDOUT;
use strict;
my $c = 0;
my $malformed_header = 0;
open(TRUE_STDOUT, '>', '/dev/stdout');
tie *STDOUT, __PACKAGE__, (*STDOUT);

sub TIEHANDLE {
    my $class = shift;
    my $handles = [@_];
    bless $handles, $class;
    return $handles;
}

sub PRINT {
    my $class = shift;
    if (!$c++ && @_[0] !~ /^content-type/) {
        my (undef, $file, $line) = caller;
        print STDERR "Missing content-type in $file at line $line!!\n";
        $malformed_header = 1;
    }
    return 0 if ($malformed_header);
    return print TRUE_STDOUT @_;
}
1;


use MY_STDOUT;
print "content-type: text/html\n\n"; #try commenting out this line
print "<html>\n";
print "</html>\n";
```

In a more Perl-Moosy way?

For example should I do

```
open(TRUE_STDOUT, '>', '/dev/stdout');
tie *STDOUT, __PACKAGE__, (*STDOUT);
```

in a BUILD{} function?

Would it make more sense to implement this as a Moosy class or as Moose::Role?

And finally, would I have to do something like

```
my $MY_STDOUT = MY_STDOUT->new();
```

to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it with IO::Scalar

https://gist.github.com/1250048

Now I just need to figure out how to do it for STDOUT!

Comment: To answer the question you didn't give a chance to answer elsewhere, I would never downvote someone for misunderstanding something.