# Is there a way to be notified when 'print' is called on $fh?

Tags: perl, filehandle

When I do:

```
print $fh 'text';
```

I need a some `&sub` to be called.

It there a way to do that?

Comment: `sub myprint { mysub(); print @_ }` perhaps? (you can't use a sub named `sub`, its a reserved name)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/387702/725418

Comment: Replace the file handle with a tied file handle

Comment: While you can overwrite a lot of built-ins, you cannot do that for `print`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/CORE.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`tie` a filehandle](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltie#Tying-FileHandles) and customize the behavior for `print`ing to that filehandle or for any other operation on that filehandle.

```
sub PrintNotifier::TIEHANDLE {
    my ($pkg, $orignalHandle) = @_;
    bless { glob => $orignalHandle }, $pkg;
}
sub PrintNotifier::PRINT {
    my ($self,@msg) = @_;
    ... do whatever you want with @msg here ...
    return print {$self->{glob}} @msg;
}
sub PrintNotifier::CLOSE { return close $_[0]->{glob} }

open my $fh, '>', 'some-file';
tie *$fh, 'PrintNotifier', $fh;
print $fh "something";           # calls  PrintNotifier::PRINT
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `tie` the handle, as mob suggested.  Or, if you can change the code and your Perl is new enough, you can replace

```
print $fh 'text';
```

with

```
$fh->print('text');
```

which you might consider cleaner syntax; then you *can* sub-class IO::File:

```
package MyFH {
    use parent qw/ IO::File /;
    use mro; # Get next::method

    sub print {
        my ($self, @args) = @_;

        warn 'Printing ', @args;
        $self->next::method(@args);
    }
}

my $fh = MyFH->new();
$fh->open('file', '>') or die $!;
```

However, this *doesn't* capture the old-fashioned

```
print $fh 'text';
```

style.

Depending on your preference, you might find the new style cleaner anyway, since if your file handle is an expression it allows

```
$obj->method()->print('text');
```

instead of

```
print {$obj->method()} 'text';
```

It works transparently for Perl 5.14 and up, and can be made to work for older Perls back to (at least) 5.8 by adding

```
use IO::Handle;
```

to the top of the files you want to use it in (just to be on the safe side).

Answer (score 0):

In is not documented in [perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) but has usefull [usage](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/IO-String-1.08/String.pm)

If you want to process **print**'ing on your object in your class you can **tie** into itself:

```
tie *$self, $self;
print $self 'text';
$self->print( 'text' );
```