# Create Perl function which accepts optional file handle like built-in print?

Tags: perl

How to declare the function prototype if I want to get similar parameter passing as built-in `print`, like accepts optional first parameter which is file handle? For example, the calling syntax would be `myprint $filehandle @mylist`.

Comment: You don't need a prototype. You should never use prototypes unless you're certain what you're doing and have a great reason.Just pass the lexical file handle as a parameter. Don't use global file handles. If you need to use a built-in file handle like `STDOUT` then pass a reference to the glob: `\*STDOUT`.

Comment: @Borodin Well, I think the question is about the special syntax of `print`: the filehandle is optional and is _not_ followed by a comma `, `. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388211/5830574) is an interesting answer about redefining `print`. They say it doesn't work.

Comment: @Perl: `print $fh` uses `$fh` as an object with a `print` method. It's only valid Perl because it's an established idiom, and it really should be `$fh->print(...)`. If the OP wants that then they should subclass `IO::File`, but it would have to be a very special requirement to need such chicanery.

Comment: @Thomson: Why do you want to do this? What do you need that ordinary subroutines can't offer? It's very odd to want to write something that pretends to be part of the language when it's clearly not.

Comment: @Borodin, I am trying to write a logging method and want to get similar syntax as built-in `print`, like if `$filehandle` is not specified, just log to console. I thought `print` is just an built-in Perl function and I could mimic it in my code.

Comment: @Thomson: `print` is a built-in operator, but why do you want to emulate it? What's wrong with `sub myprint { ... }`? I assume you wouldn't want to write a replacement for `use`, `for`, `next` etc.?

Comment: Just for similarity. I assumed it is in special prototype but I am wrong. Switching to normal Perl function is fine.

Comment: @Thomson: The last thing you want is apparent  *similarity* when what you're writing is actually completely different from the core operator.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of `print` can't be replicated by Perl subs.

```
$ perl -le'print defined(prototype("CORE::print")) ? "Can" : "Can'\''t", " be replicated"'
Can't be replicated
```

Specifically, the syntax `NAME EXPR LIST` can't be used to call a Perl sub because the syntax is for an indirect method call. `NAME EXPR LIST` already means `EXPR->NAME(LIST)`

**Option 1**

```
# myprint $fh, LIST
# myprint *FH, LIST
# myprint \*FH, LIST

sub myprint {
   my $fh = shift;
   ...
}
```

**Option 2**

```
# myprint $fh, LIST
# myprint *FH, LIST
# myprint \*FH, LIST
# myprint FH, LIST

sub myprint(*@) {
   my $fh = shift;
   if (!ref($fh)) {
      $fh = caller().'::'.$fh if $fh !~ /^(?:ARGV|STD(?:IN|OUT|ERR))\z/;
      no strict qw( refs );
      $fh = \*$fh;
   }

   ...
}
```

---

On the flip side, even `print` doesn't actually support `print EXPR LIST`. It supports the following syntaxes:

```
print LIST         # Short for: print { select() } LIST
print IDENT LIST   # Short for: print { \*IDENT  } LIST
print $VAR LIST    # Short for: print { $VAR     } LIST
print BLOCK LIST
```

You can actually support the final form of `print` (for which the others are merely shortcuts):

```
# myprint { select } LIST
# myprint { $fh } LIST
# myprint { *FH } LIST
# myprint { \*FH } LIST

sub myprint(&@) {
   my $fh = shift->();
   ...
}
```

I like this solution less than the first two.

Comment: Any reference about `NAME EXPR LIST` syntax? Haven't got meaning answer via literal search.

Comment: You mean indirect method call syntax? A [search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Aperldoc.perl.org+indirect+method+call+syntax) leads to [this](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax)

Answer (score 3):

`print $fh @list` as an example of an indirect method call, equivalent to

```
$fh->print(@list)
```

To use a different function that can be indirectly invoked with a filehandle, define it in the `IO::Handle` package.

```
sub IO::Handle::myprint {
    my ($self, @list) = @_;
    #$self->print(scalar localtime,": ",@list);
    print $self scalar localtime, ": ", @list;
}

open my $fh, '>', 'foo';
print $fh "hello\n";          # IO::Handle::print($fh, "hello\n")
myprint $fh "world\n";        # IO::Handle::myprint($fh, "world\n")
close $fh;
```

<strike>This works with Perl v5.16 and better, and doesn't work with Perl v5.12 and earlier, for reasons I haven't investigated (maybe it's because it's not until v5.14 or v5.16 that all filehandles are automatically blessed into `IO::File`)</strike>

This seems to work on all versions of Perl back to at least v5.8. It's the syntax `$self->print(...)` inside the `myprint` method that requires v5.16 (or maybe v5.14, whenever it was that all filehandles were automatically blessed into `IO::File`) -- `print $self ...` still works with older Perls.

Comment: `print $fh @list` isn't a method call (indirect or otherwise), and it's not equivalent to `$fh->print(@list)` or `IO::Handle::print($fh, "hello\n")`.

Comment: `$fh->print(@list)` has worked since 5.8, but you had to make sure IO::Handle was loaded until 5.14.

Comment: Finally, and most importantly, you're are advocating monkey-patching a basic class for no reason. That's horrible advice!

Comment: No, I'm advocating monkey-patching a basic class for a reason.

Comment: Elaborate. Even if the OP had asked to create a method for all file handles (which they didn't), that wouldn't be a reason for doing it. (It would be a reason to tell them not to do it.) What possible reason is there to add `myprint` to IO::Handle?

Comment: To create new functions that can be invoked with `func FILEHANDLE LIST` syntax.

Comment: But that's not what you did; you did far far more than that. /// I also see your answer still claims that `print $fh` is equivalent to `$fh->print`. Unlike the latter, the former doesn't call `IO::Handle::print` (unlike what your comment claims).