# is it allowed to pass pipes to constructors?

Tags: perl

I tried to do something very fancy in Perl, and I think I'm suffering the consequences. I don't know if what I was trying to do is possible, actually.

My main program creates a pipe like this:

```
pipe(my $pipe_reader, my $pipe_writer);
```

(originally it was pipe(PIPE_READER, PIPE_WRITER) but I changed to regular variables when I was trying to debug this)

Then it forks, but I think that is probably irrelevant here. The child does this:

```
my $response = Response->new($pipe_writer);
```

The constructor of Response is bare bones:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $writer = shift;

    my $self = {
        writer => $writer
    };
    bless($self, $class);
    return($self);
 }
```

Then later the child will write its response:

```
$response->respond(123, "Here is my response");
```

The code for respond is as follows:

```
sub respond {
    my $self = shift;
    my $number = shift;
    my $text = shift;
    print $self->{writer} "$number\n";
    print $self->{writer} "$text\n";
    close $self->{writer}
}
```

This triggers a strange compile error: 'String found where operator expected ... Missing operator before "$number\n"?' at the point of the first print. Of course this is the normal syntax for a print, except that I have the object property instead of a normal handle AND it happens to be a pipe, not a file handle. So now I'm wondering if I'm not allowed to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)

> If you're storing handles in an array or hash, or in general whenever you're using any expression more complex than a bareword handle or a plain, unsubscripted scalar variable to retrieve it, you will **have to use a block returning the filehandle value** instead,  ...
>
> ```
> print { $files[$i] } "stuff\n";
> print { $OK ? *STDOUT : *STDERR } "stuff\n";
> ```

(my emphasis)

So you need

```
print { $self->{writer} } "$number\n";
```

---

Or, per [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s comment

```
$self->{writer}->print("$number\n");
```

The syntax of `print` is special, see for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/387702/4653379) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48195133/4653379). For one, after `print` must come either a "simple" filehandle or *a block* evaluating to one, as quoted above, to satisfy the parser.

But with the [dereference (arrow) operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) the filehandle is found to be an [IO::File](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html) object<sup>†</sup> and so its parent's [IO::Handle::print](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html) method is invoked on it.
Prior to v5.14 there had to be `use IO::Handle;` for this to work, though not anymore. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412630/4653379) and links in it for more.

Note that `print FILEHANDLE LIST` is not an [indirect method call](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax),
even as it may appear to be. It is just a function call to the `print` builtin under rather special syntax rules. It is only with an explicit `->`
that an `IO::Handle` method gets called.

---

<sup>†</sup> It is either blessed into the class as the method call is encountered (and fails), or at creation; I can't find it in docs or otherwise resolve whether filehandles are blessed at creation or on demand

```
perl -MScalar::Util=blessed -wE'
    pipe(RD,WR);                   
    say *WR{IO};                   #--> IO::File=IO(0xe8cb58)
    say blessed(WR)//"undef";      #--> undef
'
```

(warns of unused `RD`)   We can't do this with lexical filehandles as they are not in the symbol table.

But once needed a filehandle *is* an `IO::File` or `IO::Handle` object (depending on Perl version).

Comment: Or `$self->{writer}->print("$number\n")`

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you. Definitely needed be mentioned -- updated.